# Java annotation to require a specific return type

Tags: java, annotations

I have an annotation to mark some methods so I can later use reflection and call those methods. Because of using reflection, I want to make sure that if you make your method, it is returning the type I am expecting it.

Let's just say I want these marked methods to be returning a `String`, i.e.

```
// This is valid
@Mark
public String method1() {}

// This should raise an error
@Mark
public int method2() {}
```

Is it possible that I declare the required return type of the method in my annotation?

Comment: The method declaration already do that ... but you can set a `Class` instance to the annotation to do that. But this will be redondant. You are the one adding the annotation, you are the one defining the method ... use interface to define a contract for your method instead

Comment: @AxelH similar to `@Test` methods for unit testing, these methods that will bed `@Mark` will increase in volume. So everytime a new method comes along, I don't wan to update the interface for it. How do I set the `Class` instance in my annotation?

Comment: If you say so, I still don't see the point of having annotation linked to a method declaration to check ... The declaration... Check how to define a variable in annotation... You need to follow a tutorial if you don't because you can't use an annotation at runtime just like that.